# How to get two text elements inline in react native with tailwind

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

i am trying to align two text elements in react native but they end up with a small gap
[image]

```
        <View style={tailwind('flex-row mb-2 justify-between')}>
          <Text>
            Text 1
          </Text>
            {!visible && (
              <Text>
                Text 2
              </Text>
            )}
        </View>
```

i have also tried to do it like this, but i am not able to pull Text 2 to the right this way.

```
        <View style={tailwind('flex-row mb-2 justify-between')}>
          <Text>
            Text 1
            {!visible && (
              <Text>
                Text 2
              </Text>
            )}
          </Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `flex-row` to simply `flex`. flex-row is only setting `flex-direction: row` (the flexbox default direction), but it's not setting `display: flex`...

```
    <View style={tailwind('flex mb-2 justify-between')}>
       <Text>
          Text 1
       </Text>
       {!visible && (
         <Text>
            Text 2
         </Text>
       )}
   </View>
```

https://codeply.com/p/UgPU3XXoui